# xcodebuild install path?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcodebuild

I am developing an iphone app using xcode. I would like to automate the "build and run" process, and so want to know if there is any way to install the built app on simulator or device.

There is `xcodebuild install` command but i don't know how to set the installation directory `DSTROOT` to simulator/device. Please help me there.

I have looked through many forums where people suggest just to use xcode GUI to do the stuff, and I do that too, but I would really like to know the command-line way.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is copy the built .app from wherever XCode puts it to ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/[somefolder]/, with a file named [somefolder].sb (alongside the folder, not in it) containing the following:

```
(version 1)
(debug deny)
(allow default)
```

Then launch /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone Simulator. And select your App. Without Jailbreaking it's NOT possible to install it from outside the GUI.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply woodleader. But I was looking for a more flexible option. I have more than one mac in my team for the dev, and this would not solve the problem of automating the whole process, since wach will have different [somefolder]s. Also, xcodebuild has an option of "install" and I think it leads to a better solution, I just dont know how and what.

Answer (score 3):

The `install` build action for Xcode will only copy the built product to the install path specified in the xcode project.

This is used for frameworks and libraries that need installing after being built so that other apps can link against them from a common location.

I don't think you'll be able to use this build action to automate the Build and Run process - that is going to have to be done manually by each developer. There is no way to push apps onto a device without using Xcode, iTunes or the iPhone Configuration utility. As for the Simulator, it's as woodleader says. But for the device, without jailbreaking and writing your own code, you can't do this.

What you can do is use xcodebuild to generate daily/nightly builds for continuous integration. You can write a script that checks out the source form version control, runs xcodebuild and puts the built product in an easy to reach location. The installtion onto devices will still need to be done manually however.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying that Jasarien. Guess I'll need to stick with xcode GUI for device testing. And I'll give it to woodleader for elaborating the steps involved.

Comment: "There is no way to push apps onto a device without using Xcode, iTunes or the iPhone Configuration utility." - no longer true as you can now deploy OTA by creating an IPA/manifest (see Apple docs)

Comment: You're right, that is another way to install apps to iOS devices - however, you still can't **push** apps to a device using the OTA method. Even with the OTA feature, you can't automate Xcode to install an app OTA. You could automate the process of creating the IPA and manifest and uploading that to the server where it will be hosted, but the install will still need to be manual.